# Google поиск на python

Tags: python, google-search

Мне нужно настроить поиск в google через Python чтобы просто получать первые 3-4 ссылки со страницы. Для этого я установил библиотеку гугл и написал следующее:

```py
from googlesearch import search
query = "ititaniumcoin.com telegram"
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=3, stop=1, pause=40):
    print(j)
```

Но постоянно получаю ошибку `429 too many requests`. Как это можно обойти?

Comment: как именно установил и как именно называется модуль? pip такого модуля не находит

Comment: pip3 install google

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/google/

Comment: Ставил. Не находит там search.

Comment: pip3 install google надо, а не pip install